# Showing SQL server data on map in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a projects which demands implementing a map interface. For example I have list of numerous patient in India which show various disease. The patient are divided State wise. On execution the disease should display map of India. The state which has the highest number of patient in India should be painted with a different color. Similarly the map should paint top five States with different color which has highest number of patient.

I have come up with a code snippet which displays just a static map of India. I need to fill colors in it to show top five states that contain highest number of patient.

The data is stored in sql server 2008

```
<map id="latitude-and-longitude-map-of-india" name="latitude-and-longitude-map-of-india">
  <area shape="poly" alt="Jammu & Kashmir" coords="184,143,177,138,171,139,171,134,156,127,153,101,163,95,164,89,159,87,160,82,151,78,150,74,142,74,144,67,151,60,162,59,160,55,166,58,172,53,176,54,177,55,183,53,193,65,204,72,206,77,215,80,215,84,226,82,236,76,241,76,243,72,246,76,254,76,259,80,257,97,252,98,251,100,248,101,249,107,246,110,241,109,239,112,241,116,240,119,240,123,246,125,251,136,240,140,237,139,237,136,230,138,229,134,226,137,219,129,213,133,205,127,198,127,191,132,192,135,188,141"
                                            href="Jammu.aspx" title="Jammu & Kashmir" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Himachal Pradesh" coords="202,165,203,161,198,159,197,160,194,156,192,148,188,146,188,141,192,135,191,133,197,127,205,127,213,134,218,129,226,136,230,134,231,138,236,149,236,154,239,162,227,162,222,166,221,177,212,176,210,170,205,167"
                                            href="Himachal Pradesh.aspx" title="Himachal Pradesh" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Punjab" coords="156,183,159,181,159,175,171,164,171,153,172,148,181,144,183,142,188,142,188,146,192,147,193,154,197,160,199,159,203,161,202,165,207,168,207,176,201,180,196,183,195,189,183,189,181,190,176,184,168,185"
                                            href="Punjab.aspx" title="Punjab" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Haryana" coords="187,212,183,201,182,197,171,196,169,185,176,184,180,190,183,189,194,189,196,183,207,177,207,168,211,172,212,176,218,177,213,183,211,191,212,203,212,204,206,207,206,211,211,213,215,211,217,217,216,222,207,226,207,219,206,216,202,220,197,218,194,224,191,221,193,214"
                                            href="Haryana.aspx" title="Haryana" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Delhi" coords="213,208,212,203,205,208,206,211,211,213,215,211"
                                            href="Delhi.aspx" title="Delhi" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Uttrakhand" coords="253,166,248,167,244,159,241,157,238,162,228,162,221,166,221,177,223,180,221,183,220,189,225,190,227,189,231,185,234,193,238,194,237,198,249,205,257,205,260,198,261,194,262,187,270,181,271,178,259,174,258,170"
                                            href="Uttrakhand.aspx" title="Uttrakhand" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Uttar Pradesh" coords="228,241,220,240,215,243,215,240,220,238,217,237,218,232,211,225,217,221,217,215,214,210,211,204,211,190,214,180,220,176,223,180,221,183,220,189,225,190,228,188,231,185,234,193,238,194,237,198,249,205,257,205,263,209,267,208,279,216,286,222,290,222,299,225,302,229,310,231,313,228,319,229,328,244,320,246,325,249,322,251,323,254,331,259,322,262,312,270,312,275,315,280,313,283,312,290,309,294,302,292,302,288,302,280,296,280,293,278,288,276,287,273,281,272,278,272,276,275,271,274,270,273,263,273,261,267,253,272,246,270,243,272,239,269,237,267,232,269,238,281,240,284,238,288,233,286,230,286,228,278,228,275,231,272,230,268,234,265,237,263,238,258,243,250,239,245,235,243,229,242"
                                            href="Uttar Pradesh.aspx" title="Uttar Pradesh" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Rajasthan" coords="112,278,104,264,105,260,98,258,96,255,96,252,98,244,90,242,87,239,87,234,96,224,101,217,107,219,108,223,111,224,116,222,124,221,132,211,133,206,142,201,144,200,150,189,150,185,155,183,169,185,171,195,171,196,182,197,187,212,193,214,191,221,194,224,197,218,202,220,206,216,207,220,207,226,211,224,211,225,218,232,217,237,220,238,215,240,215,243,221,240,227,241,225,243,208,254,202,259,200,262,203,268,211,268,214,267,214,273,205,274,206,279,210,280,208,284,205,284,206,291,201,288,195,288,188,295,183,294,185,291,188,291,187,284,189,283,188,279,179,280,180,274,179,273,175,277,173,277,171,282,172,285,171,287,173,287,173,297,167,302,170,306,164,308,152,299,148,295,149,290,144,288,146,284,144,281,141,284,126,278,111,278"
                                            href="Rajasthan.aspx" title="Rajasthan" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Madhya Pradesh" coords="160,328,160,323,159,323,160,318,164,315,165,311,164,308,170,306,167,302,173,297,173,288,171,287,172,284,171,282,173,277,175,277,179,273,180,274,179,280,182,280,188,279,189,283,187,284,188,291,185,291,183,294,187,295,188,295,195,288,201,288,206,291,205,284,208,284,210,280,206,279,205,274,214,273,214,267,211,268,204,268,200,262,203,258,208,254,223,244,227,241,230,242,236,243,239,245,243,250,238,258,237,263,230,268,231,271,228,275,228,280,230,286,233,286,238,288,240,284,232,269,237,267,243,272,246,270,253,272,261,267,263,273,269,273,276,275,278,272,285,272,288,274,288,276,296,280,302,280,302,292,299,296,284,295,284,301,290,300,294,305,293,308,290,309,283,319,277,320,271,330,270,339,267,340,261,334,256,336,247,333,238,336,233,337,228,336,223,339,217,338,216,332,209,333,204,336,202,342,196,345,192,338,178,338,173,334,166,333,161,336,156,335,156,330"
                                            href="Madhya Pradesh.aspx" title="Madhya Pradesh" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Gujarat" coords="125,338,109,348,99,346,79,327,84,325,87,325,87,324,77,324,74,318,75,316,80,320,95,315,101,307,101,305,98,308,86,311,70,304,66,294,68,294,73,291,71,291,64,294,63,290,73,288,73,284,88,284,90,286,94,287,98,283,102,283,104,286,107,286,111,283,111,278,126,278,141,284,144,281,146,284,144,288,149,290,148,295,157,303,164,308,165,311,164,315,160,318,159,323,160,323,160,328,156,330,156,335,160,336,159,338,153,342,156,347,156,351,151,352,150,350,148,352,147,360,144,360,142,357,136,359,136,356,140,351,139,348,137,341,135,338,135,336,141,332,134,332,137,327,135,325,137,323,129,321,128,327,125,328,126,330,128,331,129,334"
                                            href="Gujarat.aspx" title="Gujarat" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Dadar & Nagar Haveli" coords="140,361,139,358,141,357,143,358,143,360"
                                            href="http://www.mapsofindia.com/lat_long/dadraandnagarhaveli/" title="Dadar & Nagar Haveli" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Maharashtra" coords="147,433,144,422,141,401,137,385,137,373,134,364,136,359,139,359,140,361,144,360,146,360,147,360,148,352,150,350,151,352,156,351,156,347,153,342,160,338,160,336,161,335,166,333,168,334,173,334,178,338,192,338,196,345,202,342,204,336,209,333,216,332,217,338,223,339,228,336,234,337,242,335,247,333,255,336,261,334,267,341,264,345,268,351,267,358,265,360,267,362,266,366,273,371,272,376,267,373,263,380,263,387,258,386,256,380,258,377,257,372,253,370,250,373,245,370,240,370,235,367,230,367,228,376,223,377,222,381,223,384,218,390,217,394,214,394,212,391,210,396,206,397,203,402,197,405,196,411,183,408,182,411,185,413,184,418,179,418,175,419,172,417,171,420,167,424,162,423,161,425,164,430,164,433,160,439,155,440,154,438,150,439"
                                            href="Maharashtra.aspx" title="Maharashtra" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Goa" coords="157,454,159,452,161,446,160,439,155,440,153,438,150,439,154,446,156,455"
                                            href="Goa.aspx" title="Goa" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Karnataka" coords="169,489,165,470,162,461,157,455,159,452,161,445,160,439,164,433,164,429,161,425,162,423,167,424,171,420,172,417,175,419,178,418,184,418,185,413,182,411,183,408,196,411,197,405,203,402,206,397,210,396,212,391,214,394,217,394,218,402,215,404,215,407,218,408,214,414,216,416,215,424,212,426,216,430,215,436,209,436,208,441,207,446,209,447,209,451,204,452,204,459,205,464,206,469,209,465,213,465,212,469,207,471,207,474,211,474,213,472,215,475,219,474,223,472,227,473,226,476,231,478,231,482,234,483,235,486,228,492,222,490,217,496,217,499,215,502,215,502,219,502,219,507,215,508,215,510,206,510,203,513,196,511,190,505,186,506,179,500,177,494,169,490"
                                            href="Karnataka.aspx" title="Karnataka" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Kerala" coords="209,572,211,568,210,565,210,561,209,558,213,552,214,549,210,548,211,537,210,536,203,537,205,528,201,525,203,522,202,520,198,520,198,517,194,515,194,512,196,511,190,505,186,506,179,500,177,494,169,490,178,509,185,519,191,536,197,550,194,551,201,565"
                                            href="Kerala.aspx" title="Kerala" />
  <area shape="circle" alt="Pondicherry" coords="257,518,2" href="http://www.mapsofindia.com/lat_long/pondicherry/"
                                            title="Pondicherry" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Tamil Nadu" coords="230,558,237,557,242,554,246,555,246,553,241,553,240,550,246,542,248,536,257,536,257,519,256,520,255,519,255,516,256,509,256,504,262,497,266,488,264,479,261,478,255,483,250,483,247,487,238,487,235,490,235,494,231,494,228,492,222,490,217,496,217,499,215,501,215,502,219,502,219,507,215,508,215,510,206,510,203,513,195,511,194,512,194,515,198,517,198,520,202,520,203,522,201,525,205,528,203,537,210,536,211,538,210,548,214,549,212,554,209,558,210,562,210,566,211,568,209,573,215,577,225,570,227,563,229,559"
                                            href="Tamilnadu.aspx" title="Tamil Nadu" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Andhra Pradesh" coords="260,447,265,438,269,436,276,438,282,427,289,428,297,425,300,419,297,416,307,408,317,401,327,392,338,381,339,378,337,377,331,382,331,384,323,382,319,376,315,380,315,383,310,386,309,392,306,390,303,393,300,389,299,394,298,397,292,398,288,400,288,404,286,406,285,410,282,412,275,415,272,418,268,417,266,419,268,422,267,423,261,419,259,424,248,426,244,432,238,435,232,436,227,439,219,439,215,436,209,436,207,446,209,447,209,452,204,452,204,459,206,469,209,465,213,465,212,469,207,471,207,474,211,474,213,472,215,475,220,474,223,472,227,473,226,476,230,478,231,478,231,482,234,483,235,486,228,492,230,494,235,494,235,490,238,487,247,487,250,483,255,483,261,478,264,479,262,472,261,467,262,463,261,456,260,448"
                                            href="Andhra Pradesh.aspx" title="Andhra Pradesh" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Chhattisgarh" coords="298,365,290,361,291,365,295,375,295,383,288,392,284,394,282,401,282,402,277,402,272,394,270,389,266,388,264,389,262,387,263,386,263,380,267,373,272,376,273,371,266,366,267,363,265,360,267,358,268,351,264,345,267,341,266,340,269,339,270,339,271,329,277,320,283,319,290,309,293,308,294,305,290,300,284,301,284,295,299,296,302,292,309,294,313,289,322,299,324,297,325,309,330,309,326,315,325,315,325,320,318,324,315,334,312,342,302,343,297,350,299,361,302,363,302,366"
                                            href="Chhattisgarh.aspx" title="Chhattisgarh" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Orissa" coords="362,363,352,366,343,372,337,377,331,382,331,384,324,382,323,382,319,376,315,380,315,383,310,386,309,392,306,390,303,393,300,389,298,397,292,398,285,401,282,401,284,394,289,391,295,383,295,374,291,364,290,361,299,365,302,366,302,362,302,363,299,361,297,350,302,343,312,342,318,324,325,320,328,320,333,319,339,318,341,317,341,324,344,325,347,323,353,324,356,326,358,322,357,315,364,318,370,322,375,325,383,331,373,335,372,338,375,350,369,355,364,360,361,361"
                                            href="Orissa.aspx" title="Orissa" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Jharkhand" coords="381,286,385,282,385,274,385,267,383,264,380,264,374,269,372,278,364,279,364,282,361,282,360,279,356,276,351,276,349,279,343,282,340,283,336,282,329,284,326,280,321,280,314,281,313,285,313,289,322,299,324,297,325,309,330,309,326,315,324,315,325,320,330,320,341,317,341,323,341,324,344,325,347,323,353,324,356,326,358,322,357,315,364,318,369,322,371,318,369,314,365,311,365,308,360,308,358,305,353,303,354,299,358,298,361,299,364,295,370,295,371,291,375,292,377,289"
                                            href="Jharkhand.aspx" title="Jharkhand" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Bihar" coords="351,243,349,242,349,239,344,240,341,240,339,238,335,237,332,236,332,230,327,230,324,228,319,229,328,244,320,246,325,249,322,251,323,254,331,259,322,262,312,270,312,275,315,280,314,281,326,280,329,284,336,282,340,283,349,279,351,276,356,276,360,279,361,282,364,282,364,279,372,278,374,269,380,264,383,264,385,261,387,261,387,258,383,253,390,246,389,243,386,245,374,245,369,244,366,245,359,242,351,244"
                                            href="Bihar.aspx" title="Bihar" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="West Bengal" coords="401,325,405,330,409,327,407,315,404,303,404,300,401,300,401,295,398,293,398,290,400,290,400,282,393,280,389,277,389,273,393,271,395,266,402,265,400,261,396,261,391,255,388,255,388,251,392,247,394,243,398,246,401,246,403,244,407,250,411,250,413,246,416,244,415,237,404,236,400,234,397,230,387,232,389,236,389,243,390,246,383,253,387,258,387,261,385,261,383,264,385,267,385,282,377,289,375,292,371,291,370,295,364,295,361,299,358,298,354,299,353,303,358,305,360,308,364,308,365,308,365,312,364,311,369,314,371,318,369,321,369,321,383,331,387,328,390,326,394,326,396,330,399,328,400,325"
                                            href="West Bengal.aspx" title="West Bengal" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Sikkim" coords="386,228,388,218,395,213,399,217,397,224,400,227,398,230,386,233"
                                            href="Sikkim.aspx" title="Sikkim" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Meghalaya" coords="462,263,466,261,463,258,462,255,458,253,454,253,455,247,450,247,440,253,435,251,422,251,417,253,418,262,430,264,448,263,451,262,455,263,458,265"
                                            href="Meghalaya.aspx" title="Meghalaya" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Tripura" coords="460,280,459,288,454,290,453,294,452,295,451,302,449,302,446,298,446,300,440,289,443,283,451,279,457,276"
                                            href="Tripura.aspx" title="Tripura" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Mizoram" coords="465,275,470,276,470,280,476,281,478,291,478,299,474,300,474,309,476,312,472,318,467,316,462,302,460,292,459,288,460,280,464,278"
                                            href="Mizoram.aspx" title="Mizoram" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Manipur" coords="490,282,476,281,470,280,469,276,471,274,472,268,476,260,479,259,481,252,489,254,492,252,495,256,494,258,497,259,496,266,492,277"
                                            href="Manipur.aspx" title="Manipur" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Nagaland" coords="483,248,485,239,494,230,501,225,502,232,500,234,501,240,501,247,499,253,495,256,492,252,488,254,481,252,479,260,476,260,476,257,473,254,480,248"
                                            href="Nagaland.aspx" title="Nagaland" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Asom" coords="475,229,468,230,462,229,454,232,451,232,440,234,432,234,432,235,424,233,420,236,415,236,416,244,415,245,416,248,418,254,417,252,418,253,422,251,435,251,440,253,450,247,455,247,454,253,458,253,462,255,463,258,466,260,465,262,460,264,460,267,458,268,457,276,460,280,464,278,465,275,470,276,471,273,472,268,476,260,476,257,473,254,480,248,483,248,485,239,491,233,494,230,501,225,503,225,506,221,514,219,514,216,511,216,510,213,510,210,512,207,510,206,504,209,489,216,486,216,481,223,478,228,474,229"
                                            href="Assam.aspx" title="Asom" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Arunachal Pradeh" coords="523,216,522,218,515,220,505,231,502,232,501,226,503,225,507,221,514,218,514,216,510,215,510,210,512,207,512,207,510,206,489,216,486,216,481,223,478,228,470,230,462,229,454,232,448,232,452,229,451,223,450,222,443,220,443,215,448,217,453,214,456,216,460,212,459,209,469,204,469,199,479,197,481,191,489,185,492,188,501,189,502,184,510,180,516,183,512,187,514,190,519,186,520,192,516,198,518,199,523,197,534,200,533,203,535,204,528,210,529,215,533,220,531,220,529,219,526,216"
                                            href="Arunachal Pradesh.aspx" title="Arunachal Pradeh" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Telangana" coords="216,430,212,426,215,424,216,416,214,414,218,408,215,407,215,404,218,402,217,393,217,390,218,391,223,384,222,381,223,377,228,376,230,367,236,367,240,371,240,370,245,370,250,373,252,371,253,370,257,372,258,377,256,379,258,386,262,387,264,389,266,387,270,389,274,396,277,402,282,403,282,401,286,401,288,400,288,405,286,406,285,410,275,415,272,418,268,417,266,419,268,422,267,423,261,419,259,424,248,426,244,432,238,435,233,436,226,439,219,439,215,436,216,430"
                                            href="Telangana.aspx" title="Telangana" />
  <area shape="default" nohref="nohref" alt="" />
                                    </map>
```

my .cs code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;


public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    public DateTime textToDate(string strdate)
    {
        return DateTime.ParseExact(strdate, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }
    protected void Generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection
        con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        //da = new SqlDataAdapter("select state from SR @fromdate='" + textToDate(TxtFromDate.Text.ToString()).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "',@Todate='" + textToDate(TxtToDate.Text.ToString()).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "' ", con);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select state from SR", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        ddlState.DataSource = ds;
        ddlState.DataValueField = "State";
        ddlState.DataTextField = "State";

        ddlState.DataBind();

        cmd.Dispose();
        con.Dispose();

        con.Close();

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection
        con1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

        da1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select [CST Case ID], [CST Case Subtype], [State Name] from SR ", con1);
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        da1.Fill(ds1);
        Grdvw.DataSource = ds1;
        Grdvw.DataBind();

        cmd1.Dispose();
        con1.Dispose();
    }
}
```

1. I want to show my SR data on map of India.. But I don't know how to call this data from SQL to map page.
2. How to call Sql server data OnClick event of map region?
3. Showing my data on map as a colour category of 5 type as highest to lowest category.
4. Want 2 show this type of data on image calling from Sql Server 2008
   List item [image: Want 2 show this type of data on image]
5. How should I fill the colour on calling data of Sql Server 2008.

I found some article for changing this but this article is based on java. I don't know java on complex level below is the code. Can any one help to  convert this java code on c# and asp.net

Ex. For 1-1000 population i have to show red colour. For 1000-5000 population i have to show blue colour.

I'm using code like this.But it is not displaying different colours based on the range of population

```
var mapData = {
  "AF": 1000,
  "AL": 5000,
  "DZ": 20000,
  ...
};

     try{
                        $('#id').vectorMap(
                        {
                            map : 'world_mill_en',
                            series : {
                                regions : [ {
                                    initial : {
                                        fill : 'white',
                                        "fill-opacity" : 1,
                                        stroke : 'none',
                                        "stroke-width" : 0,
                                        "stroke-opacity" : 1
                                    },
                                    hover : {
                                        "fill-opacity" : 0.8
                                    },
                                    selected : {
                                        fill : 'yellow'
                                    },
                                    selectedHover : {},
                                    values : mapData,
                                    scale : [  '#C8EEFF', '#0071A4' ],
                                    normalizeFunction : 'polynomial'
                                } ]
                            },
                            onRegionLabelShow : function(e, el, code) {
                                el.html(el.html()+' (Population - '+mapData[code]+')');
                            }
                        });
            }
    catch(err){
            alert(err);
        }
```

and some one is given answer to this article. The answer is below:
Create a JSON with count and color codes like this according to your regions and colors.

```
var colorData = {
     "1" : "#C8EEFF", 
     "2" : "#0071A4",
     "3" : "#C8EEFF", 
     "4" : "#0071A4",
     "5" : "#C8EEFF", 
     "6" : "#0071A4"
}
```

and pass this JSON to the scale : colorData.

Please suggest for converting this code into asp.net. Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us what have you tried.

Comment: go through with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29480620/how-to-event-listen-and-programatically-highlight-specific-regions-of-my-india-m

Comment: My map is showing  static data it means only showing map of India and after clicking state wise. It shows the particular state. the code is below:

Comment: Plz suggest some idea behind this project

Answer (score 1):

This is not easy to do using the `MAP` tag because it does not by itself support coloring the hotspots (the clickable areas). You can try this plugin: http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/ which looks promising. It allows you to color hotspots and do highlighting and coloring.

Other ideas for displaying the map:

1. **Recommended:** Tile-based maps, like Leaflet and MapBox. Example: http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html
2. SVG. Here are some free SVG maps of India: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:SVG_maps_of_India
   I copied part of one for a very simple proof of concept showing how to display data by clicking on SVG paths: http://jsfiddle.net/d4hrbu8p/
3. HTML Canvas. (not recommended)

For getting data from SQL Server: It looks like you are already binding to a GridView to display the raw data. This is good - you must then associate the records from the grid with a specific state's shape object. If you keep using the `MAP` tag you first must assign `id` attributes to each of your `AREA` elements. You could then use JavaScript (and the above plugin) to associate each data point to a state shape.

**Here is a very simple proof of concept.** The map image you linked in your question did not match your `MAP` dimensions, so I just faked it.

Click `Show code snippet` then scroll down and click `Run code snippet` to view it. Then click around the map. I only defined data for a few states, but you should get the idea.

```js
$("area[shape='poly']").on("click", function() {
  var stateName = $(this).prop("alt");
  var displayText = stateName;

  var $stateRow = $("#data tbody tr").filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("state") === stateName;
  });

  if ($stateRow && $stateRow.length) {

    // found data; display it 
    // code is proof of concept only; better to use JSON data, or something cleaner than screenscraping the table

    var cancerCases = $stateRow.children(':nth-child(2)').text();
    var aidsCases = $stateRow.children(':nth-child(3)').text();
    var sarsCases = $stateRow.children(':nth-child(4)').text();

    displayText += '\nCancer cases: ' + cancerCases + '\nAIDS cases: ' + aidsCases + '\nSARS cases: ' + sarsCases;


  } else {
    displayText += '\nNO DATA DEFINED FOR THIS STATE';
  }


  alert(displayText);
  return false; // temporarily disabled navigation... do stuff here if needed
});
```

```css
img {
  height: 600px;
  /* img did not match map; this is just a hack to show proof of concept, not accurate dimensions */
}
td,
th {
  padding: 6px 12px;
}
th {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBJui.jpg' usemap='latitude-and-longitude-map-of-india' />
<map id="latitude-and-longitude-map-of-india" name="latitude-and-longitude-map-of-india">
  <area shape="poly" alt="Jammu & Kashmir" coords="184,143,177,138,171,139,171,134,156,127,153,101,163,95,164,89,159,87,160,82,151,78,150,74,142,74,144,67,151,60,162,59,160,55,166,58,172,53,176,54,177,55,183,53,193,65,204,72,206,77,215,80,215,84,226,82,236,76,241,76,243,72,246,76,254,76,259,80,257,97,252,98,251,100,248,101,249,107,246,110,241,109,239,112,241,116,240,119,240,123,246,125,251,136,240,140,237,139,237,136,230,138,229,134,226,137,219,129,213,133,205,127,198,127,191,132,192,135,188,141"
  href="Jammu.aspx" title="Jammu & Kashmir" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Himachal Pradesh" coords="202,165,203,161,198,159,197,160,194,156,192,148,188,146,188,141,192,135,191,133,197,127,205,127,213,134,218,129,226,136,230,134,231,138,236,149,236,154,239,162,227,162,222,166,221,177,212,176,210,170,205,167"
  href="Himachal Pradesh.aspx" title="Himachal Pradesh" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Punjab" coords="156,183,159,181,159,175,171,164,171,153,172,148,181,144,183,142,188,142,188,146,192,147,193,154,197,160,199,159,203,161,202,165,207,168,207,176,201,180,196,183,195,189,183,189,181,190,176,184,168,185" href="Punjab.aspx"
  title="Punjab" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Haryana" coords="187,212,183,201,182,197,171,196,169,185,176,184,180,190,183,189,194,189,196,183,207,177,207,168,211,172,212,176,218,177,213,183,211,191,212,203,212,204,206,207,206,211,211,213,215,211,217,217,216,222,207,226,207,219,206,216,202,220,197,218,194,224,191,221,193,214"
  href="Haryana.aspx" title="Haryana" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Delhi" coords="213,208,212,203,205,208,206,211,211,213,215,211" href="Delhi.aspx" title="Delhi" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Uttrakhand" coords="253,166,248,167,244,159,241,157,238,162,228,162,221,166,221,177,223,180,221,183,220,189,225,190,227,189,231,185,234,193,238,194,237,198,249,205,257,205,260,198,261,194,262,187,270,181,271,178,259,174,258,170"
  href="Uttrakhand.aspx" title="Uttrakhand" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Uttar Pradesh" coords="228,241,220,240,215,243,215,240,220,238,217,237,218,232,211,225,217,221,217,215,214,210,211,204,211,190,214,180,220,176,223,180,221,183,220,189,225,190,228,188,231,185,234,193,238,194,237,198,249,205,257,205,263,209,267,208,279,216,286,222,290,222,299,225,302,229,310,231,313,228,319,229,328,244,320,246,325,249,322,251,323,254,331,259,322,262,312,270,312,275,315,280,313,283,312,290,309,294,302,292,302,288,302,280,296,280,293,278,288,276,287,273,281,272,278,272,276,275,271,274,270,273,263,273,261,267,253,272,246,270,243,272,239,269,237,267,232,269,238,281,240,284,238,288,233,286,230,286,228,278,228,275,231,272,230,268,234,265,237,263,238,258,243,250,239,245,235,243,229,242"
  href="Uttar Pradesh.aspx" title="Uttar Pradesh" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Rajasthan" coords="112,278,104,264,105,260,98,258,96,255,96,252,98,244,90,242,87,239,87,234,96,224,101,217,107,219,108,223,111,224,116,222,124,221,132,211,133,206,142,201,144,200,150,189,150,185,155,183,169,185,171,195,171,196,182,197,187,212,193,214,191,221,194,224,197,218,202,220,206,216,207,220,207,226,211,224,211,225,218,232,217,237,220,238,215,240,215,243,221,240,227,241,225,243,208,254,202,259,200,262,203,268,211,268,214,267,214,273,205,274,206,279,210,280,208,284,205,284,206,291,201,288,195,288,188,295,183,294,185,291,188,291,187,284,189,283,188,279,179,280,180,274,179,273,175,277,173,277,171,282,172,285,171,287,173,287,173,297,167,302,170,306,164,308,152,299,148,295,149,290,144,288,146,284,144,281,141,284,126,278,111,278"
  href="Rajasthan.aspx" title="Rajasthan" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Madhya Pradesh" coords="160,328,160,323,159,323,160,318,164,315,165,311,164,308,170,306,167,302,173,297,173,288,171,287,172,284,171,282,173,277,175,277,179,273,180,274,179,280,182,280,188,279,189,283,187,284,188,291,185,291,183,294,187,295,188,295,195,288,201,288,206,291,205,284,208,284,210,280,206,279,205,274,214,273,214,267,211,268,204,268,200,262,203,258,208,254,223,244,227,241,230,242,236,243,239,245,243,250,238,258,237,263,230,268,231,271,228,275,228,280,230,286,233,286,238,288,240,284,232,269,237,267,243,272,246,270,253,272,261,267,263,273,269,273,276,275,278,272,285,272,288,274,288,276,296,280,302,280,302,292,299,296,284,295,284,301,290,300,294,305,293,308,290,309,283,319,277,320,271,330,270,339,267,340,261,334,256,336,247,333,238,336,233,337,228,336,223,339,217,338,216,332,209,333,204,336,202,342,196,345,192,338,178,338,173,334,166,333,161,336,156,335,156,330"
  href="Madhya Pradesh.aspx" title="Madhya Pradesh" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Gujarat" coords="125,338,109,348,99,346,79,327,84,325,87,325,87,324,77,324,74,318,75,316,80,320,95,315,101,307,101,305,98,308,86,311,70,304,66,294,68,294,73,291,71,291,64,294,63,290,73,288,73,284,88,284,90,286,94,287,98,283,102,283,104,286,107,286,111,283,111,278,126,278,141,284,144,281,146,284,144,288,149,290,148,295,157,303,164,308,165,311,164,315,160,318,159,323,160,323,160,328,156,330,156,335,160,336,159,338,153,342,156,347,156,351,151,352,150,350,148,352,147,360,144,360,142,357,136,359,136,356,140,351,139,348,137,341,135,338,135,336,141,332,134,332,137,327,135,325,137,323,129,321,128,327,125,328,126,330,128,331,129,334"
  href="Gujarat.aspx" title="Gujarat" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Dadar & Nagar Haveli" coords="140,361,139,358,141,357,143,358,143,360" href="http://www.mapsofindia.com/lat_long/dadraandnagarhaveli/" title="Dadar & Nagar Haveli" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Maharashtra" coords="147,433,144,422,141,401,137,385,137,373,134,364,136,359,139,359,140,361,144,360,146,360,147,360,148,352,150,350,151,352,156,351,156,347,153,342,160,338,160,336,161,335,166,333,168,334,173,334,178,338,192,338,196,345,202,342,204,336,209,333,216,332,217,338,223,339,228,336,234,337,242,335,247,333,255,336,261,334,267,341,264,345,268,351,267,358,265,360,267,362,266,366,273,371,272,376,267,373,263,380,263,387,258,386,256,380,258,377,257,372,253,370,250,373,245,370,240,370,235,367,230,367,228,376,223,377,222,381,223,384,218,390,217,394,214,394,212,391,210,396,206,397,203,402,197,405,196,411,183,408,182,411,185,413,184,418,179,418,175,419,172,417,171,420,167,424,162,423,161,425,164,430,164,433,160,439,155,440,154,438,150,439"
  href="Maharashtra.aspx" title="Maharashtra" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Goa" coords="157,454,159,452,161,446,160,439,155,440,153,438,150,439,154,446,156,455" href="Goa.aspx" title="Goa" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Karnataka" coords="169,489,165,470,162,461,157,455,159,452,161,445,160,439,164,433,164,429,161,425,162,423,167,424,171,420,172,417,175,419,178,418,184,418,185,413,182,411,183,408,196,411,197,405,203,402,206,397,210,396,212,391,214,394,217,394,218,402,215,404,215,407,218,408,214,414,216,416,215,424,212,426,216,430,215,436,209,436,208,441,207,446,209,447,209,451,204,452,204,459,205,464,206,469,209,465,213,465,212,469,207,471,207,474,211,474,213,472,215,475,219,474,223,472,227,473,226,476,231,478,231,482,234,483,235,486,228,492,222,490,217,496,217,499,215,502,215,502,219,502,219,507,215,508,215,510,206,510,203,513,196,511,190,505,186,506,179,500,177,494,169,490"
  href="Karnataka.aspx" title="Karnataka" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Kerala" coords="209,572,211,568,210,565,210,561,209,558,213,552,214,549,210,548,211,537,210,536,203,537,205,528,201,525,203,522,202,520,198,520,198,517,194,515,194,512,196,511,190,505,186,506,179,500,177,494,169,490,178,509,185,519,191,536,197,550,194,551,201,565"
  href="Kerala.aspx" title="Kerala" />
  <area shape="circle" alt="Pondicherry" coords="257,518,2" href="http://www.mapsofindia.com/lat_long/pondicherry/" title="Pondicherry" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Tamil Nadu" coords="230,558,237,557,242,554,246,555,246,553,241,553,240,550,246,542,248,536,257,536,257,519,256,520,255,519,255,516,256,509,256,504,262,497,266,488,264,479,261,478,255,483,250,483,247,487,238,487,235,490,235,494,231,494,228,492,222,490,217,496,217,499,215,501,215,502,219,502,219,507,215,508,215,510,206,510,203,513,195,511,194,512,194,515,198,517,198,520,202,520,203,522,201,525,205,528,203,537,210,536,211,538,210,548,214,549,212,554,209,558,210,562,210,566,211,568,209,573,215,577,225,570,227,563,229,559"
  href="Tamilnadu.aspx" title="Tamil Nadu" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Andhra Pradesh" coords="260,447,265,438,269,436,276,438,282,427,289,428,297,425,300,419,297,416,307,408,317,401,327,392,338,381,339,378,337,377,331,382,331,384,323,382,319,376,315,380,315,383,310,386,309,392,306,390,303,393,300,389,299,394,298,397,292,398,288,400,288,404,286,406,285,410,282,412,275,415,272,418,268,417,266,419,268,422,267,423,261,419,259,424,248,426,244,432,238,435,232,436,227,439,219,439,215,436,209,436,207,446,209,447,209,452,204,452,204,459,206,469,209,465,213,465,212,469,207,471,207,474,211,474,213,472,215,475,220,474,223,472,227,473,226,476,230,478,231,478,231,482,234,483,235,486,228,492,230,494,235,494,235,490,238,487,247,487,250,483,255,483,261,478,264,479,262,472,261,467,262,463,261,456,260,448"
  href="Andhra Pradesh.aspx" title="Andhra Pradesh" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Chhattisgarh" coords="298,365,290,361,291,365,295,375,295,383,288,392,284,394,282,401,282,402,277,402,272,394,270,389,266,388,264,389,262,387,263,386,263,380,267,373,272,376,273,371,266,366,267,363,265,360,267,358,268,351,264,345,267,341,266,340,269,339,270,339,271,329,277,320,283,319,290,309,293,308,294,305,290,300,284,301,284,295,299,296,302,292,309,294,313,289,322,299,324,297,325,309,330,309,326,315,325,315,325,320,318,324,315,334,312,342,302,343,297,350,299,361,302,363,302,366"
  href="Chhattisgarh.aspx" title="Chhattisgarh" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Orissa" coords="362,363,352,366,343,372,337,377,331,382,331,384,324,382,323,382,319,376,315,380,315,383,310,386,309,392,306,390,303,393,300,389,298,397,292,398,285,401,282,401,284,394,289,391,295,383,295,374,291,364,290,361,299,365,302,366,302,362,302,363,299,361,297,350,302,343,312,342,318,324,325,320,328,320,333,319,339,318,341,317,341,324,344,325,347,323,353,324,356,326,358,322,357,315,364,318,370,322,375,325,383,331,373,335,372,338,375,350,369,355,364,360,361,361"
  href="Orissa.aspx" title="Orissa" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Jharkhand" coords="381,286,385,282,385,274,385,267,383,264,380,264,374,269,372,278,364,279,364,282,361,282,360,279,356,276,351,276,349,279,343,282,340,283,336,282,329,284,326,280,321,280,314,281,313,285,313,289,322,299,324,297,325,309,330,309,326,315,324,315,325,320,330,320,341,317,341,323,341,324,344,325,347,323,353,324,356,326,358,322,357,315,364,318,369,322,371,318,369,314,365,311,365,308,360,308,358,305,353,303,354,299,358,298,361,299,364,295,370,295,371,291,375,292,377,289"
  href="Jharkhand.aspx" title="Jharkhand" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Bihar" coords="351,243,349,242,349,239,344,240,341,240,339,238,335,237,332,236,332,230,327,230,324,228,319,229,328,244,320,246,325,249,322,251,323,254,331,259,322,262,312,270,312,275,315,280,314,281,326,280,329,284,336,282,340,283,349,279,351,276,356,276,360,279,361,282,364,282,364,279,372,278,374,269,380,264,383,264,385,261,387,261,387,258,383,253,390,246,389,243,386,245,374,245,369,244,366,245,359,242,351,244"
  href="Bihar.aspx" title="Bihar" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="West Bengal" coords="401,325,405,330,409,327,407,315,404,303,404,300,401,300,401,295,398,293,398,290,400,290,400,282,393,280,389,277,389,273,393,271,395,266,402,265,400,261,396,261,391,255,388,255,388,251,392,247,394,243,398,246,401,246,403,244,407,250,411,250,413,246,416,244,415,237,404,236,400,234,397,230,387,232,389,236,389,243,390,246,383,253,387,258,387,261,385,261,383,264,385,267,385,282,377,289,375,292,371,291,370,295,364,295,361,299,358,298,354,299,353,303,358,305,360,308,364,308,365,308,365,312,364,311,369,314,371,318,369,321,369,321,383,331,387,328,390,326,394,326,396,330,399,328,400,325"
  href="West Bengal.aspx" title="West Bengal" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Sikkim" coords="386,228,388,218,395,213,399,217,397,224,400,227,398,230,386,233" href="Sikkim.aspx" title="Sikkim" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Meghalaya" coords="462,263,466,261,463,258,462,255,458,253,454,253,455,247,450,247,440,253,435,251,422,251,417,253,418,262,430,264,448,263,451,262,455,263,458,265" href="Meghalaya.aspx" title="Meghalaya" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Tripura" coords="460,280,459,288,454,290,453,294,452,295,451,302,449,302,446,298,446,300,440,289,443,283,451,279,457,276" href="Tripura.aspx" title="Tripura" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Mizoram" coords="465,275,470,276,470,280,476,281,478,291,478,299,474,300,474,309,476,312,472,318,467,316,462,302,460,292,459,288,460,280,464,278" href="Mizoram.aspx" title="Mizoram" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Manipur" coords="490,282,476,281,470,280,469,276,471,274,472,268,476,260,479,259,481,252,489,254,492,252,495,256,494,258,497,259,496,266,492,277" href="Manipur.aspx" title="Manipur" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Nagaland" coords="483,248,485,239,494,230,501,225,502,232,500,234,501,240,501,247,499,253,495,256,492,252,488,254,481,252,479,260,476,260,476,257,473,254,480,248" href="Nagaland.aspx" title="Nagaland" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Asom" coords="475,229,468,230,462,229,454,232,451,232,440,234,432,234,432,235,424,233,420,236,415,236,416,244,415,245,416,248,418,254,417,252,418,253,422,251,435,251,440,253,450,247,455,247,454,253,458,253,462,255,463,258,466,260,465,262,460,264,460,267,458,268,457,276,460,280,464,278,465,275,470,276,471,273,472,268,476,260,476,257,473,254,480,248,483,248,485,239,491,233,494,230,501,225,503,225,506,221,514,219,514,216,511,216,510,213,510,210,512,207,510,206,504,209,489,216,486,216,481,223,478,228,474,229"
  href="Assam.aspx" title="Asom" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Arunachal Pradeh" coords="523,216,522,218,515,220,505,231,502,232,501,226,503,225,507,221,514,218,514,216,510,215,510,210,512,207,512,207,510,206,489,216,486,216,481,223,478,228,470,230,462,229,454,232,448,232,452,229,451,223,450,222,443,220,443,215,448,217,453,214,456,216,460,212,459,209,469,204,469,199,479,197,481,191,489,185,492,188,501,189,502,184,510,180,516,183,512,187,514,190,519,186,520,192,516,198,518,199,523,197,534,200,533,203,535,204,528,210,529,215,533,220,531,220,529,219,526,216"
  href="Arunachal Pradesh.aspx" title="Arunachal Pradeh" />
  <area shape="poly" alt="Telangana" coords="216,430,212,426,215,424,216,416,214,414,218,408,215,407,215,404,218,402,217,393,217,390,218,391,223,384,222,381,223,377,228,376,230,367,236,367,240,371,240,370,245,370,250,373,252,371,253,370,257,372,258,377,256,379,258,386,262,387,264,389,266,387,270,389,274,396,277,402,282,403,282,401,286,401,288,400,288,405,286,406,285,410,275,415,272,418,268,417,266,419,268,422,267,423,261,419,259,424,248,426,244,432,238,435,233,436,226,439,219,439,215,436,216,430"
  href="Telangana.aspx" title="Telangana" />
  <area shape="default" nohref="nohref" alt="" />
</map>
<table id='data'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>State</th>
      <th>Cancer cases</th>
      <th>AIDS cases</th>
      <th>SARS cases</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-state='Punjab'>
      <td>Punjab</td>
      <td>4564554</td>
      <td>55466</td>
      <td>23434</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-state='Telangana'>
      <td>Telangana</td>
      <td>43453</td>
      <td>3422</td>
      <td>3346</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-state='Jharkhand'>
      <td>Jharkhand</td>
      <td>6234</td>
      <td>25234</td>
      <td>665427</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-state='Rajasthan'>
      <td>Rajasthan</td>
      <td>362</td>
      <td>432</td>
      <td>7982</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-state='Uttar Pradesh'>
      <td>Uttar Pradesh</td>
      <td>44300</td>
      <td>45345</td>
      <td>24324</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is a complex project, and I recommend you break it into steps. First get the map showing to your satisfaction, then move on to getting the data from SQL server. Take it one step at a time.

NOTE: I used javascript and jQuery for this. You don't need jQuery, but it makes things easier.